# ionic4 app generate iOS files without www folder

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm using ionic CLI version 4.12.0 to create an app, when I use this command `ionic Cordova platform add ios` 
ionic CLI adding the Xcode files of my App, but when I run the App on the real device I get this error
`ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found`.
and

```
Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'
```

I think my ionic CLI does not generate the www folder files like in ionic3 CLI, is there something missing. www folder is totally empty and not shown in Xcode files

Comment: Adding the platform might not be enough. Have you tried running `ionic cordova prepare ios` aswell?

Comment: @Phonolog, buddy you saved my day, please answer the question so I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Glad it helped, I added a short answer :)

Comment: So I'm I @Phonolog thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments `ionic cordova platform add ios` will only download the needed tools for iOS.

To build the www directory, run `ionic cordova prepare ios` after adding the platform.

According to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-prepare), `ionic cordova prepare ios` does the following:

> - Perform an Ionic build, which compiles web assets to www/.
> - Copy the www/ directory into your Cordova platforms.
> - Transform config.xml into platform-specific manifest files.
> - Copy icons and splash screens from resources/ to into your Cordova platforms.
> - Copy plugin files into specified platforms.